# How to debug the LibreOffice extension written in Python in VisualStudio

Tags: python, visual-studio, libreoffice

Good afternoon.

I installed the LibreOffice extension (https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/calendar-for-calc).

The structure of the **pycalendar-4-0-1.oxt** shown in the screenshot.

[image]

**Question**:
How to debug python code in Visual Studio when working with an extension in LibreOffice.

Comment: Personally, I use the logging module and also catch and write to file any top-level exceptions in the file where the extension's services and components are defined (mine is called Components.py). Also, pylint and unit testing suites help find problems. In short, I don't use a debugger. But if you get it working, please post an answer in case other people want to do the same.